# Getting query string variable from browser with backend server-side c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a simple controller, inside my .NetCore project, that connects to a 3rd party API requesting an authorization code.

The controller is here:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult RequestAuth(string returnUrl = "/")

{
    var token = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("AuthAccessCode");
    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
}
```

This controller connects to the 3rd party API, and then that API redirects the browser to a defined URL that I specify, with the authorization code appended in the query string like this:

```
https://zod.es.able.edu/reports/EndPoint.htm?AuthCode=6932
```

Now, I need to read the AuthCode, which I do with javascript.  Then I need to do a POST event to the same API to get a really long security token.

But the makers of the 3rd-party API say it has to be done from my server, not the client browser side.  If I do the POST request client-side, like in Javascript, they deny the request.  The request has to come from my backend (c#) server.

There is where I am getting hung up on.  Because I know how to do it clientside, with Ajax or something like that.

But how could the server back-end code(c#) retrieve the AuthCode, and then make a POST request to the API?

I wouldn't even know where to begin?

Is there a library for something like this?

Thank you!

Comment: Here's where you begin: HttpClientFactory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: @insane_developer thanks!  I read through that and see I can do a POST using HttpMethod.Post.  But, how would it handle knowing when and how to get the AuthCode querystring variable? Right now, I am using Javascript to get the querystring, but it's the server that needs it, not the clientside.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to look into HTTP Requests in c#. You can look at this resource for more information:

https://www.google.com/search?q=httprequests+in+.net+c%23&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA849CA849&oq=httprequests+in+.net+c%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3386j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

http://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/

**Googling "making API requests in .net core" will be very helpful as well.**

As for getting the query string inside your controller you can do so using the request object in the current HttpContext.

```
var queryStringCollection= Request.Query;
```

or

```
var queryStringCollection = HttpContext.Request.Query;
```

This will return a collection of all query string values or you can use:

```
var queryString = Request.QueryString;
```

or

```
var queryString = HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
```

Which will return the raw query string.

Can get more information here:

https://forums.asp.net/t/1441380.aspx?how+to+get+query+string+in+Controller+

Comment: Thanks!  How would the server-side c# code, "know" that the API redirected the browser to URL that contains the queryString?  What I mean is, how could I fire a POST request using IHttpClientFactory whenever the a browser hits the URL? Or is that not possible?

Comment: For doing 3rd party authentication redirects the flow usually goes like this: user clicks a link with an href value set to the url you want them to redirect, after authentication happens you get a "callback" (request) sent to action you have setup at that point you can use HttpClient to get the authentication token from the API.

Comment: Hi Nolan, yes! That makes sense!  Because the user does click a Button on a webpage.  That Button click, fires off to the 3rd party API, which then loads another web page, which is the redirect specified.  This new URL contains the AuthCode value.  I then need to use that AuthCode value in the query string to make a server-side POST call to the API(which then returns the needed token value).

Comment: Correct, when the redirect happens it will hit the endpoint in your controller. You can have a parameter for that code that is passed back or get it from Request.Query (or Request.QueryString). At that point you create an http request and send it to the API with that code. You get the result of that request (which will contain the token) and then you can use that token to make requests for that user later.

Comment: Thanks Nolan, I think I understand, but just one quick followup...when the redirect happens, that redirect URL should be a controller?

Comment: Yes, the redirect url you usually set on your account for the 3rd party API. This url will be a url to some action in your controller. Ex. https://localhost:5000/Test/Callback

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use .net core HttpClient for making requests from server side code.
Here is the official docs for that

[HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1)

Here is a small sample code :-

```
        public HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var postData= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header
        var request = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");//CONTENT-TYPE header
        var res = await client.PostAsync(yourUrl, request );
        var finalResult = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Declaring an HttpClient in this way can cause some problems. Reusing clients with IHttpClientFactory is best practice. In the HttpClient docs it states the issue and offers the solution of using a static client.